# field output dependend on mime type of another field

Tags: theming, files

I have a node type with 2 fields: preview_image and file (multivalue).

I can upload image and video files.

For the output I need the following:

The preview_image should only be displayed when the first file of the file field (multivalue) has a specific mime type (in my case any video mime type).

Is there a solution for that?

UPDATE:

Now we have a change in field structure. We use 2 mime types, images and videos. But for the images we need a cropping function. And we need an easy possibility to arrange the files within node editor.

Now we would like to create 2 new node types - for example 'image' and 'video'. In both node types we create the file fields - in 'image' with the cropping function.

In the main node type we now create 2 fields as entity references to get the files.

Now we need a solution to display the preview image only when the referenced node is of type 'video'.

**Show preview image:**

media element (referencing field)

- entity of type 'video' (referenced entity)
- entity of type 'image' (referenced entity)
- entity of type 'image' (referenced entity)
- entity of type 'video' (referenced entity)

**Don't show preview image**

- entity of type 'image' (referenced entity)
- entity of type 'image' (referenced entity)
- entity of type 'video' (referenced entity)
- entity of type 'image' (referenced entity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a template preprocess added to the template.php file in your theme. You would need to test for the video mime type on the correct node and then use Drupal's [hide](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7) function, to tell Drupal to skip the field on render.

```
    /**
     * Override or insert variables into the node templates.
     *
     * @param $variables
     *   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
     * @param $hook
     *   The name of the template being rendered ("node" in this case.)
     */
    function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {
      $type = $variables['type'];

      switch ($type) {

          case 'NODE_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME':

            if (isset($variables['FILE_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME'][0])) {
              $mime_type = $variables['FILE_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME'][0]['filemime'];
              $mime_regex = '/^video/';
              // We have to check the string for the presence of "video", because it could be any of 18 video mime types. 
              $is_video = preg_match($mime_regex, $mime_type);

              if ($is_video) {
                hide($variables['content']['IMAGE_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']);
              }

            }
          break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Big thanks for your help!

But please have a look at my question update.

Answer (score 0):

Per the update, your code inside your main nodes preprocess would need to change to check the type of the referenced node and hide dependent upon that.

```
 if (!empty($variables['REFERENCE_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME'])) {
     $referenced_nid = $variables['REFERENCE_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];

     // Load the referenced node to get the type
     $node = node_load($referenced_nid);
     $type = $node->type; 

     if ($type == 'video') {
       hide($variables['content']['IMAGE_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']);
     }
 }
```

You may need to use Devel and output `$variables` to get your tailor this to your field.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Do I use this code in node.tpl of my node type? Or in template.php?

Comment: This is all template.php code.

Comment: Sorry, on my side it doesn't work.

Let me explain my config in detail:

I have a content type **header_slider**. In this ct I have 2 fields: **header_slider_element** (the referencing field, multivalue) and **field_header_slider_previews_img** (the preview image). **header_slider_element** refers to 2 content types: **header_slider_element_img** and **header_slider_element_video**.

The **field_header_slider_previews_img** should only be displayed, when the first (referenced node) value of **field_slider_element** is of node type **header_slider_element_video**.

My code at the moment:

Comment: `if (!empty($variables['field_slider_element'])) {
     $referenced_nid = $variables['field_slider_element'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];

     // Load the referenced node to get the type
     $node = node_load($referenced_nid);
     $type = $node->type; 

     if ($type == 'header_slider_element_video') {
       hide($variables['content']['field_header_slider_previews_img']);
     }
 };`

Comment: I would start by using Devel module to `dpm($variables)`. Check that `$variables['field_slider_element'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id']` is correct in your use case. Keep in mind `LANGUAGE_NONE` is replacing `und`.